# How to avoid k-means to merge two groups of points into one cluster?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I've implemented a *k-means* clustering algorithm, but in some cases (~12%) a situation like that happened:

[image: k-means graph]

In these cases, my algorithm is creating one cluster for both the yellow and blue group of points
and is dividing the purple group into two clusters. When this occurs, the cluster division becomes
23-12-65, when it should be 33-33-34.

My algorithm is:

1. Select 3 random points `c0`, `c1` and `c2` in the dataset.
2. For each point `p` in the dataset, associate `p` with the nearest `c_`.
3. For each point `c_`, set `c_` to the mean point of its associated points.
4. Repeat 2 and 3 500 times.
5. Output `c0`, `c1` and `c2`.

I'm assuming this problem happens in step 1, where two points from the purple group are selected. Is this normal for *k-means*? If there's a solution, how to fix or minimize this problem? I'm creating the
dataset using the [`sklearn.datasets.make_blobs`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html) method, so I've already tried raising the number of points to 500 (n_samples=500) and lowering the standard deviation of the data
making the points more sparse (cluster_std=0.1).

---

Some background: I'm unit testing this algorithm, so it'll assert if each of the three found centroids are inside of each square in the image. In this specific case, the assertion fails, even if in ~88% of
the cases it asserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since k-means relies on random initialisation, if local minima exist, there is no way to guarantee that the algorithm finds what might be obvious to the human eye. But, there are ways to mitigate it. One simple approach is having multiple runs for it and pick the solution with the lowest cost. This number of runs can be a parameter, maybe set to 1 as default. In the end, your unit tests should have fault tolerance or you should pick random initialisation points in a supervised manner.

Comment: Based on your answer, I decided to pick one random point from each group of points as initial centroids and proceed the algorithm from there. It worked gracefully, thanks for your help!

Comment: That's a good way to *ensure* the health of your unit tests.